# Can you set a custom field in a new post through the REST API without using any plugins?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm able to create posts using the REST API but don't see any way to define custom fields on that post without modifying the source code.

I've looked through the documentation and I don't see any support for it. It looks like you have to add it yourself (doesn't say where) or what to send in a REST call:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#working-with-registered-meta-in-the-rest-api

I've looked for plugins and I don't see any that do it. I've seen plugins that allow you to return metadata but all of these guides are old.

Is there any way to insert metadata when creating or updating a new post without using a plugin or modifying the source code?

```
var results = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "My Post",
        content: "Hello world!",
        status: 'publish',
        meta: {
            name:"favoriteColor", 
            value: "blue"
        }
    })
})
```

The code above works to create the post but doesn't create the custom fields.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question. but might be a place to start: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250614/create-taxonomy-with-meta-term-using-the-wp-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

From the guide it looks like reading and writing of custom fields are not supported out of the box.

> **register_meta** is used to whitelist an existing custom meta value for
> access through the REST API. By setting a meta field’s show_in_rest
> parameter to true, that field’s value will be exposed on a .meta key
> in the endpoint response, *and WordPress will handle setting up the
> callbacks for reading and writing to that meta key*.

So you have to add some php to register a meta key and then it is readable and writable.

There is this example code on the same page:

```
<?php
// The object type. For custom post types, this is 'post';
// for custom comment types, this is 'comment'. For user meta,
// this is 'user'.
$object_type = 'post';
$meta_args = array( // Validate and sanitize the meta value.
    // Note: currently (4.7) one of 'string', 'boolean', 'integer',
    // 'number' must be used as 'type'. The default is 'string'.
    'type'         => 'string',
    // Shown in the schema for the meta key.
    'description'  => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
    // Return a single value of the type.
    'single'       => true,
    // Show in the WP REST API response. Default: false.
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);

register_meta( $object_type, 'my_meta_key', $meta_args );
```

You can put this in your `theme_functions` page. See Appearance > Theme Editor.

[image]

Then in your code you send it defining the `meta` property and using a name value pair; the name of the key and it's value.

```
var results = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: pageTitle,
        content: markupOutput,
        status: 'publish',
        meta: {
            my_meta_key: "test"
        }
    })
})
```

Example Code:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#read-and-write-a-post-meta-field-in-post-responses

Documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#using-register_rest_field-vs-register_meta